# C# FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

I want to be able to add some amount of progressbars into the form (the number of progressbars can vary from user to user).

I have written this code to add 1 progressbar:

```
        ProgressBar progressbar = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
        progressbar.Name = "progressBar1";
        progressbar.Size = new Size(280, 30);
        progressbar.TabIndex = 9;
        progressbar.Show();
        flowLayoutPanel.Container.Add(progressbar);
```

When I run this code, I get an Exception: `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`. 
What bothers me is that both the progressbar and flowLayoutPanel aren't null when I look at them using IDE. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Maybe the flowLayoutPanel's `Container` is null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing `flowLayoutPanel.Container` is null.  I think you want

```
flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(progressbar);
```

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks a lot.
I very obvious error I have been pulling my hair out for.
Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
progressbar.Show();
```

this line should not be necessary

did you put this code before `InitializeComponents`? then `flowLayoutPanel` is null because in this function all form elements are initialized

then, the sub elements are in `FlowLayoutPanel.Controls`, not container